# No qualifying bean of type ... not defined error message on one of my repository classes

Tags: java, spring

I'm getting the following exception @ runtime

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.mbc.receiptprinter.repository.AddressRepository] is defined
```

My AddressRepository interface is defined like this:

```
package com.mbc.receiptprinter.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.mbc.receiptprinter.model.Address;

public interface AddressRepository extends JpaRepository<Address, Long> {

}
```

This is my AppConfig:

```
package com.mbc.receiptprinter.config;

import org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories
@PropertySource("classpath:Application.properties")
public class AppConfig {

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER = "db.driver";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD = "db.password";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL = "db.url";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME = "db.username";

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "hibernate.dialect";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "hibernate.show_sql";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN = "entitymanager.packages.to.scan";

    @Resource
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD));

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistence.class);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN));
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(hibProperties());
        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    private Properties hibProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL));
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

And Application.properties:

```
#DB properties:
db.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mbc
db.username=someuser
db.password=somepass

#Hibernate Configuration:
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
entitymanager.packages.to.scan=com.mbc.receiptprinter
```

Any ideas what I'm missing for this repository to be recognized?  I'm using IntelliJ as my IDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `EnableJpaRepositories` scans the package of the annotated class for data repositories. Instead, use its [`basePackages`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/config/EnableJpaRepositories.html#basePackages--) attribute to specify `com.mbc.receiptprinter.repository`.

Comment: Still getting the error when I do this...`@EnableJpaRepositories("basePackages:com.mbc.receiptprinter.repository")`...am I not putting that in right?  Also, should I remove the entitymanager.packages.to.scan param?

Comment: `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.mbc.receiptprinter.repository")` fixed it - thanks.

Comment: @ZackMacomber Sorry I missed the edit on your original comment. Yes, if you include the attribute name in the `""` quotes, it would've been part of the default attribute which is `value`, an alias for `basePackages`. You're welcome.